# Questions about definition of free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, free-modules, free-abelian-group

My professor didn’t define what is a free abelian group $G$ (on a set $X$) but I can guess out the definition.

We can define a free abelian group $G$ on a set $X$ as a [free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#Definition) on $X$ in the category of abelian groups. I don’t know if my definition coincides with the mainstream definition though.

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937861/the-category-of-z-modules-is-isomorphic-to-the-category-ab), we know, strictly speaking, abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are not the same because Abelian groups are sets with one operation and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are sets with two operations. However, they are isomorphic in the sense that the categories of abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are isomorphic.

Then two questions about the definition of free abelian groups naturally arose in my mind.

**Q1:** I saw people were talking about free abelian groups across this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001725/clarification-on-what-is-and-is-not-a-free-abelian-group), without an underlying set. I can only define a free abelian group on some set $X$. How do we define a free abelian group without an underlying set?

**Q2:** I also saw people were saying that free abelian groups are the same with free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. From the point of view of set theory, they are not the same as we mentioned above. Do people actually mean that free abelian groups are isomorphic to free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Thanks for help. Sorry for my long description but I just wanted to state things clear.

Comment: A free abelian group of rank $n$ is $\Bbb Z^n$.  Of these only $\Bbb Z$ is free.

Comment: Probably if you let $n=0$ you get the trivial group.   It's free too.  Not sure about the module stuff.

Comment: @eggnog Yea, your definition is a concrete one (which is equivalent to my definition, cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4034459/507382), *some knowledge of category theory is needed for reading the post*). The rank in your definition is actually the cardinality of the underlying set $X$ in my definition. Anyway, go bears!

Comment: Yes, all that seems to matter is $X$'s cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1** For every set $X$, there is an abelian group called "the free abelian group on $X$", which can be constructed explicitly as the group of formal $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of elements of $X$.

If $A$ is an abelian group, we say that $A$ is "free" if there exists a set $X$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to the free abelian group on $X$.

Some abelian groups are free (e.g. the trivial group, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}^2$), and some are not (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).

**Q2** What this means is that the isomorphism $F$ between the category of abelian groups and the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules has the property that $A$ is free if and only if $F(A)$ is free. In other words, this isomorphism restricts to an isomorphism between the categories of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and free abelian groups. Or in other words, when we pretend that "abelian group" and "$\mathbb{Z}$-module" are the same thing, then the two definitions of "free" also agree.

Comment: $\Bbb Z^2$ isn't free.  It's free abelian though.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is not a free *group*, but it is a free *abelian group*. The adjective has distinct meanings in these two contexts. It is confusing!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk We can regard $\mathbb Z^2$ as a free group modulo the commutativity, right? i.e. We identify $xy$ with $yx$ in the underlying generating set $\{x,y\}$ for $\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: Because of the commutativity $\Bbb Z^2$ isn't free.  The free group on two generators is $F_2$.  Otoh $F_1=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @eggnog Yea, $\mathbb Z^2$ is not free. What I wanted to say was that, $\mathbb Z^2 \cong F_2/\sim$, where $\sim$ is an equivalent relationship: $x\sim y$ if and only if $xy=yx$, where $x,y$ are the generators of $F_2$. The notation $F_2/\sim$ means the set consisting of equivalent classes under the equivalent relationship $\sim$ in $F_2$. Then $F_2/\sim$ is a group with the addition operation induced by the one in $F_2$.

Comment: This is not exactly a coherent description of the equivalence relation, but you have the right idea. If you take a free group on $n$ generators, and "abelianize it" by quotienting out by the equivalence relation you have in mind, you produce the free abelian group of rank $n$.